# Need to print the Boolean value in console output with proper formatting in python

Tags: python

I would need to print the boolean value (true or false) with the proper alignment formatting in python. May be this question is silly, but it is important to me.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

dup_list=[{"status": True, "set": False}, { "status": True, "set": False}]

fmt = "{} {}"
print fmt.format("enabled", "set")
print fmt.format('-----', '--------')

for temp in dup_list:
   print fmt.format(temp['status'], temp['set'])
```

Getting Output but not aligned propely:

```
enabled  set
-----  --------
True  False
True  False
```

But i would like to align properly the output on the screen. {} {} with empty data, the output is not aligned.  When I tried to change align as below, but it is printing integer values.

```
fmt = "{:6}  {:6}"
print fmt.format("enabled", "set")
print fmt.format('-------', '--------')

output:
enabled  set   
-------  --------
     1       0
     1       0
```

Can any one help me, how to print the true or false with properly using "format".

I would need the output as below.

```
enabled  set
-----   --------
True    False
True    False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{:6}` is assuming for numeric data.  For booleans, ask to use their string format:

```
>>> '{!s:>6}'.format(True)
'  True'
>>> '{!s:6}'.format(True)
'True  '
```

Or, don't reinvent the wheel, and use 3rd-party [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate).

Answer (score 3):

With Python 3.6, you can also use

```
In [22]: a = True

In [27]: f'{a!r:>5}'
Out[27]: ' True'

In [28]: f'{a!s:>5}'
Out[28]: ' True'
```